# is Google analytics account identifier assigned differently to the same browser for two different domains even if using the same GA UA-id?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently using the same Google analytics account id for two different domains (and cross-domain tracking not enabled, on purpose). My understanding is that Google analytics will assign the same Google analytics account id to the browser for all websites that are using the same Google analytics account  ID (even if cross-domain is not enabled), but when I check it seems that I'm assigned two separate Google analytics account id's.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you know about clientId is wrong. ClientId values are stored in cookies on a per-domain basis, and websites on one domain cannot access cookies set for another domain.

To keep the same clientId across different domains you need to implement cross-domain tracking.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en